# How java jackson deserializer handle both Boolean and Object on same field

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm working with a 3rd party JSON API, it returns data like this:

`{details: {...}, ...}`

I use Java Jackson to deserialize this JSON string into a POJO object, the field declaration is :

`@JsonProperty("details")
public Details getDetails(){...}`

and `Details` is another class.

Everything is fine until I found that API may return data like this:

`{details: false, ...}`

If details is empty, it returns `false`!!! And jackson gave me this exception:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Details] from Boolean value; no single-boolean/Boolean-arg constructor/factory method (through reference chain: ...["details"])`

So, how to handle this kind of JSON string? I only need this field to set to null if empty.

Comment: Try a custom deserializer to your POJO, returning null when `details` is a boolean, otherwise return the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message from Jackson hints that the library has bulit in support for static factory methods.  This is (perhaps) a simpler solution than a custom deserializer:

I created this example POJO, with a static factory method, annotated so that Jackson uses it:

```
public class Details {
    public String name;  // example property

    @JsonCreator
    public static Details factory(Map<String,Object> props) {

        if (props.get("details") instanceof Boolean) return null;

        Details details = new Details();
        Map<String,Object> detailsProps = (Map<String,Object>)props.get("details");
        details.name = (String)detailsProps.get("name");
        return details;
    }
}
```

test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String fullDetailsJson = "{\"details\": {\"name\":\"My Details\"}} ";
    String emptyDetailsJson = "{\"details\": false} ";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        Details details = mapper.readValue(fullDetailsJson, Details.class);
        System.out.println(details.name);
        details = mapper.readValue(emptyDetailsJson, Details.class);
        System.out.println(details);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

result is as expected:

```
My Details
null
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom JsonDeserializer to handle deserializing your `Details` object in which you either return null if you get false or pass the object to the default deserializer if it's an actual object. Pseudocode:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Details>{
    @Override
    public Details deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctx){
        //if object use default deserializer else return null
    }
}
```

You'll also have to write an ObjectMapperProvider to register your deserializer like so:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>{
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperProvider(){
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule sm = new SimpleModule();
        sm.addDeserializer(Details.class, new CustomDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(sm);
    }

    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0){
        return mapper;
    }
}
```